# Outlook custom progress bar

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am creating an outlook Add-in with C# (.NET 4.0 out look 2010) which saves the user selected files to specific file system folder and everything works fine.
The files are saved using

```
Outlook.MailItem objMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)mailitem;
objMailItem.SaveAs(string.Concat(objDir.FullName, "\\",RDate, fName + ".msg"), Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

When user selects multipe files, outlook shows a Saving dialog (eg: Saving file to ..C:\user provided path) for every file.

I am looking for creating a custom dialog that looks like:

```
Saving 1 of 10
.
.
Saving 9 of 10
```

Someone has an idea on how to 'work around' this behavior or which event to be handled/ supressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display your own Windows Form with information you need. For example:

```
form.Show();
```

or

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

Don't forget to specify the parent Outlook window handle to prevent the dialog window from hiding. You may cast the Explorer or Inspector object to the [IOleWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to get the handle.

Also you may consider adding a custom form to the explorer or inspector windows. In case of Inspectors you may use Outlook Form Regions. There is no such technology for Explorers, you have to use Windows API functions to subclass the Explorer window. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information.

But the Outlook object model doesn't provide any info or event which is fired when the item is saved to a disk/folder.